# URL replicando o caminho cada vez que aperto F5

Tags: angular, url, ftp, path

Eu subi um projeto em angular para o `FTP`, o problema é que cada vez que aperto *F5* ele repete o caminho relativo.

Então quando o acesso começa em

> www.mysite.com.br/one/auth/login
>   Ai aperto F5 ele fica assim:
>   www.mysite.com.br/one/auth/login/auth/login

E fica assim para cada vez que atualizo:

> www.mysite.com.br/one/auth/login/auth/login/auth/login
>   www.mysite.com.br/one/auth/login/auth/login/auth/login/auth/login....

Agora eu não sei se tem haver, mas foi depois de alterar o base href que aconteceu

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>SITE</title>

  <base href="#">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
```

O direcionamento está aparecendo no meu arquivo *login-routing.module.ts*

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { TelaComponent } from './tela/tela.component';

const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: LoginComponent,
  children: [
    {
      path: 'login',
      component: TelaComponent,
    },

    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'login',
      pathMatch: 'full',
    },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: 'login' },
  ],
},
{ path: '**', redirectTo: 'auth/login' }];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class LoginRoutingModule {
}
```

Comment: Sem código vai ficar difícil ajudar. Ajude a gente a te ajudar, posta seu código ai.

Comment: Então é que não sei se é especificamente uma parte do código ou se é o jeito que rodo o build no angular, eu to rodando o: ng build --base-href www.mysite.com.br/one/  --deploy-url www.mysite.com.br/one/

Comment: Posta o código que redireciona pra `auth/login`, é provável que a falha esteja lá.

Comment: Adicionei o routing que tem o redirecionamento

Comment: O problema está no contexto que vc fez o deploy, faz o teste roda --base-href . e comenta aqui o que deu

Comment: Coloquei o . no --base-href e ainda ta duplicando

Answer (score 0):

Altera o `auth/login`para `/auth/login`, e o `login` para `/login`.

Comment: Não funcionou pra mim

Comment: Tenta alterar os demais valores também, sempre colocando uma barra antes. E se houver em outras partes do código que redirecionam é ideal botar uma barra antes. Como funciona a barra? ela faz o redirecionamento começar a partir da URL do domínio, sem a barra o redirecionamento vai concatenar com o endereço atual